# What are all the known serialization formats of (unix) epoch time?

Tags: javascript, python, datetime, unix-timestamp, epoch

So, the [basic definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) of epoch time (similar to 'unix time', but not exactly: see below) and what it means is clear. However, nowhere on the wikipedia page or on any other resource I can find is it mentioned that **epoch time can be **serialized** (ie. to JSON, CSV, XML, etc.) in various equally-modern formats with varying degrees of precision**. Which is not a shock, right? Different programming languages do things in different ways. That's a given. But, the semi-consistent usage of epoch time itself across so many languages could possibly indicate one of two things:

1. an actual standard/spec, albeit a weak one with gaps
2. an informal convention-by-mistake, about which: assume nothing

(Note: I am NOT asking about ISO formatted date/time strings and the variants of those. Separate topic. Further, I'm not talking about low-level programming representations of these numbers, like signed vs. unsigned integers, 32 vs 64 bit, leap-seconds vs none, etc. Wikipedia actually covers all that. Just the various *serializations* of the epoch/unix time, ie. in a console, in JSON, in a database, etc.)

For instance, I've stumbled across at least 3 basic variants:

- 1707882022 - In seconds
- 1707882022000 - In milliseconds (no decimal indicator)
- 1707882022.159835 - In seconds, with decimal indicator and (up to) microsecond precision

Javascript, for instance, defaults to the milliseconds option, while Python 3 defaults to seconds with microsecond precision.

My question is: *is that all the known options/formats? And, is there any common specification/definition of them, or is it all just ad-hoc decisions by language designers, and so you just need to read the specs for all of them, separately?*

Bonus question: I know that translating between simple mathematical units like these is the appropriate work of programmers. But, as the life of senior programmers involves bringing junior people up to speed on such questions: are there any particular tools which specialize in transparent and ergonomical translation between these particular formats, or is it too seemingly simple/fundamental for anyone to have bothered? (I'll note that it's only simple if you already know what all the possibilities are, and how to recognize them. For which: there's seemingly no guide. And no clear reason why not.)

UPDATE: Some specs, such as [IETF RFC-7493](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7493), have attempted to reckon with this question, and to establish a level playing-field for serialization, although they don't help in documenting the current, fragmented state of play.

UPDATE: We have usefully clarified that "Unix time" and "Epoch Time" are not the same things. I don't know if it's formally specified anywhere, but (at least according to Wikipedia) "Unix (System) Time" is always counted in seconds. Whereas, the more general concept of "(Unix) Epoch Time" simply means time since Jan 1, 1970, which is counted by different programming languages in either seconds or milliseconds, at varying levels of precision. So, for the sake of clarity, I've edited my question to be about (Unix) Epoch Time, not Unix Time.

UPDATE: one poster has suggested that DateTime objects serialized directly to JSON are inherently numbers, not strings. Some serialization implementations do indeed behave that way, so we might go so far as to say that it's an unwritten convention. However, it's unfortunately not part of the JSON spec. And, because JSON payloads are often assembled via intermediate stages, it's quite common to have an end-product batch of JSON that doesn't come directly from system DateTime objects, but may have been processed/calculated, or de-/re-serialized somewhere in the pipeline, into another format. For instance, I've got a junior data scientist working in Python who has somehow managed to serialize a datestamp to JSON with 7 digits of decimal precision, rather than the conventional 6. He has no idea how/where it happened, and nothing in his toolchain coerced it to a more conventional value.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256893/discussion-on-question-by-xml-what-are-all-the-known-serialization-formats-of-un); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I’ll recommend you a bonus tool as soon as you tell me what human readable time `100000` represents exactly.

Comment: Right. Which is part of the point. This is a gap in specification. If a tool can't be written which could detect and level something so fundamental, then we ought to have either: A. Good docs which explain clearly the challenge, and how to address it B. a tool that's figured out some way to at least express the _probabilities_, or C. A new spec that sands off these rough edges, so people can spend their time on more valuable things. Yet, oddly, we have none. And, also oddly, some folks seem furious that I'd have the temerity to suggest that's a gap which somebody, somewhere might have filled.

Comment: UNIX timestamps are simply the simplest possible way to express a timestamp: a plain number. There's nothing in the format itself that would give you any additional information. So, yeah, that's where we're at. If you change anything about this format to add any additional information, it won't be a UNIX timestamp anymore, but some new format. And we already have a bunch of other formats (e.g. ISO timestamps). Is the situation ideal? No. But it's simply so simple that it is what it is at this point.

Comment: For example: if we simply had a convention of left-padding numeric epoch time-stamps with zeros, we'd at least know with 99% probability the scale of the units. You have 10 digits (and no period), of which there may or may not be leading zeros? It's seconds-based. 13 digits? It's milliseconds. That would be easy-as-pie. Yet, we oddly have an entire ISO spec for presentation to users, but seemingly no spec or even convention which would level the epoch time question with near-zero additional effort. Given how much we've specified or at least conventionalized in tech, that's an odd oversight.

Comment: UNIX timestamps are represented as _numbers_. Ints or floats. Actual native numeric types. Not strings. *Numbers.* You can't left pad a number.

Comment: Yes. But as I keep clarifying (and re-clarifying), this question is about _serialization_, out of native environments, and about interoperability; NOT about operations within a single runtime context, wherein that statement would be correct. As serialized to JSON, XML, CSV, NoSQL, etc.... datestamps become strings.

Comment: UNIX timestamps in JSON are typically still serialised as JSON numbers, which you can't left pad. — Again: it's simply the simplest possible format they came up with back when. Its advantage is precisely that it's so incredibly simple. Just a number. You can directly do time math with it, you just need the most primitive type to store it, there are no special parsers necessary. **It is what it is and it's not going to change.** Because changing it would make it not a UNIX timestamp. And yes, you need to read the docs, but that's simpler than changing anything about this format.

Comment: "Typically." But not by specification, and not in any way that is guaranteed at the point of interface. There is no spec, and we're not even talking solely about "UNIX timestamps", as UNIX timestamps are generally in seconds. Meanwhile, programming languages that may themselves _run_ on UNIX often choose to serialize _their_  *epoch time* datestamps in another way entirely: in milliseconds, or in seconds with microsecond precision or... whatever they feel like.

Comment: Any standard JSON parser is going to discard any padding on your numbers and just give you a plain number. If you want to use zero padding to indicate anything, you're now also talking about a custom JSON parser. Which… just… no.

Answer (score 3):

No, these values aren't magically interoperable. `1707882022` may be Feb 14 2024 as seconds, or Jan 20 1970 as milliseconds. No system can detect which is correct. You need to read the documentation of the relevant systems, which will hopefully tell you whether seconds or milliseconds are used, and whether they use floats or ints. Other systems may also make up additional formats as they please if it makes sense. You'll need to convert between the formats as necessary, which mostly means dividing or multiplying by 1000 as necessary and perhaps casting to float or int.

If you're working with lower level languages, you'd even need to consider whether to use a 32bit int, a 64bit int, or a float type. It's *always* a case-by-case decision.

---

You're trying to look for some magic which cannot exist. If you have understood the above point about Feb 14 vs Jan 20, then it's clear there's absolutely no way to know from a plain number itself what it represents. Since you'll be encountering these numbers in the wild, you will simply have to study the accompanying documentation. End of story.

If this is too ambiguous for your own taste, then use ISO 8601 datetimes to express your times instead of Epoch time whenever you're in control. This is another format to express timestamps, and it solves all the issues you're worrying about. You don't need to fix Epoch times, you can just use another format entirely.